# How to use CollectionView in Conjunction with connectOutlets?

Tags: ember.js

Currently i am trying make use of a CollectionView in my router and ConnectOutlets. I am fine, if i am using the collection view helper but this is in contrast to my other implementations, in which i am always leveraging connectOutlets.

What i am basically trying is:

```
connectOutlets : function(router){
  console.log("calling connectOutlets");
  router.get("applicationController").connectOutlet({
    viewClass : App.ItemsView,
    controller : App.itemController,
    context : content
  })
}

App.ItemsView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
  itemViewClass : App.ItemView,
});
```

App.ItemsView is my Subclass of CollectionView. App.itemController is an ArrayController i instantiated manually. You can see the full fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mavilein/qS3aN/12/

But actually this does not work. I am not seeing the items getting rendered.  With the collection helper it works fine, but setting the binding in the view is too static for me.
**Is the CollectionView not intended for use with connectOutlets?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you can do that, but two little tweaks need to be done in the `ItemsView`:

```
App.ItemsView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
   contentBinding: 'controller',
   itemViewClass : 'App.ItemView',
});
```

- Since a CollectionView rely on its content property, you have to bind it to its controller property. (this property is wired at connectOutlet time)
- As you define `App.ItemView` after `ItemsView`, you need to refer to it as a string, in order to let Ember.js lookup it during the ItemsView instance creation.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qS3aN/29/